# Analyzing an Oracle dump 

Tags: oracle-10g

I have a full Oracle dump, I know I have to `imp` the dump with the `fromuser touser` clause.

However, I don't know the names of the schemas included in the dump.  How can I open the dump created with Oracle 10g just to check and analyze the content?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `SHOW=Y` option for imp

From the manual at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm#sthref2498

> When SHOW=y, the contents of the export dump file are listed to the display and not imported. 
>   The SQL statements contained in the export are displayed in the order in which Import will execute them.
>   The SHOW parameter can be used only with the FULL=y, FROMUSER, TOUSER, or TABLES parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting is that oracle dump files are a stream format with snippets of SQL embedded.  You can also use sed to do substitutions on it, such as schema names.